# managing cpu usage

Tags: wpf, interop

Every time timer ticks the application keep on using extra memory.
How to dispose the handle in GetActeWindowTitle() and window2?
How should i manage the memory usage for this?

my Code :

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    Window2 window2 ;

    System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer1;
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        timer1 = new Timer();
        timer1.Interval = 900000; 
        timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1Tick);
        timer1.Start();             
    }

    private void timer1Tick( object Sender, EventArgs e )
    {                               
        window2 = new window2Window();

        if (((GetActeWindowTitle().IndexOf("Outlook") != -1) ||
        (GetActeWindowTitle().IndexOf("Word") != -1)))
        {
            window2.Close();
        }
        else
        {
             window2.Show();
             window2.Topmost = true;
        }   
    }

    private string GetActeWindowTitle()
    {
        const int nChars = 256;
        IntPtr handle = IntPtr.Zero;
        StringBuilder Buff = new StringBuilder(nChars);
        handle = GetForegroundWindow();
        if (GetWindowText(handle, Buff, nChars) > 0)
        {
            return Buff.ToString();             
        }
        return null;
    }       
}
```

Comment: Is your question about CPU usage or memory? What is `window2Window` and does it implement IDisposable? How are you measuring the memory usage and does it go down after a garbage collection?

Comment: Why are you creating the windows2 and then .Close?  Why not only new the window2Window in the else?

Comment: when i look at taskmanager ,memory is going up for every timer tick.

Comment: @BalamBalam i donot want to show window2 when outlook is active window.

Comment: Why new window2() before you check if Outlook active?

Comment: @BalamBalam thank you for your reply.Sorry i did not get what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe by releasing the memory that gets allocated from that Interop call referenced in the IntPtr.

Try this after using you handle in GetActeWindowTitle():

```
Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(handle);
```

Comment: thank you very much for your reply. i used Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(handle) .still memory leaking.i mean for every 15 min 100k.

Answer (score 0):

Why create new window2Window only to close it?

```
// window2 = new window2Window(); 

if (((GetActeWindowTitle().IndexOf("Outlook") != -1) || 
(GetActeWindowTitle().IndexOf("Word") != -1))) 
{ 
    // window2.Close(); 
} 
else 
{ 
    window2 = new window2Window();
    window2.Show(); 
    window2.Topmost = true; 
}
```